# How do I rotate a line around a central axis until it is parallel to x axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have all the points shown in this image. I need to rotate the top line so that it is parallel to the x-axis but it has to rotate around the point (0, 0).

[image]

Comment: Are you rotating in the plane or rotating in 3-dimensional space? If the latter, your diagram suggests that you might have to rotate about a given axis, but your question is far from clear.

Comment: I am rotating an object through 3d space, but I am only concerning my self with one side of it at a time. So that's why it has to rotate around the center point. I think looking at it as a plane should be enough, as long as it rotates around point (0, 0)

Comment: I see now what you mean. I am sorry I mixed up all the words. here is a new image with clearer labels. https://i.imgur.com/Dcud7gB.png

Comment: Compare the "target" drawing to the starting drawing and use geometry to find out how much rotation is required.

Comment: You need to rotate about the $x$-axis and you want the segment to end up parallel to the $x$-axis? That can't happen. When you rotate about the $x$-axis, the angle with that axis does not change.

Comment: Thanks Moti that makes sense.

Comment: I my rotation working yeah :) https://youtu.be/HHq-yMF397Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec{\ell} = (\ell_x, \ell_y)$ describe the line segment as a vector in the original coordinates.  If you construct unit vector $\hat{u} = (u_x, u_y)$,
$$\hat{u} = \left[\begin{matrix} u_x \\ u_y \end{matrix}\right] = \frac{\vec{\ell}}{\left\lVert\vec{\ell}\right\rVert} = \left[\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle \frac{\ell_x}{\sqrt{\ell_x^2 + \ell_y^2}} \\
\displaystyle \frac{\ell_y}{\sqrt{\ell_x^2 + \ell_y^2}} \\
\end{matrix}\right]$$
then rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ will rotate points so that $\vec{\ell}$ will end up on the positive $x$ axis (meaning the original line segment will be *parallel* to the $x$ axis):
$$\mathbf{R} = \left[\begin{matrix} u_x & u_y \\ -u_y & u_x \\ \end{matrix}\right] \tag{1a}\label{G1a}$$
In particular, if $\ell_x^2 + \ell_y^2 = 1$, then
$$\mathbf{R} \vec{\ell} = \left[\begin{matrix} \ell_x & \ell_y \\ -\ell_y & \ell_x \end{matrix} \right] \left[\begin{matrix} \ell_x \\ \ell_y \end{matrix} \right] = \left[\begin{matrix} \ell_x^2 + \ell_y^2 \\ - \ell_y \ell_x + \ell_x \ell_y \\
\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right]$$
If, for any reason, you don't need the rotation matrix but the angle of the rotation $\theta$ (positive counterclockwise), then use
$$\theta = \operatorname{atan2}(-\ell_y ,\, \ell_x) \tag{1a}\label{G1b}$$

If you want to limit the rotation to -90° to +90°, i.e. a rotation $\mathbf{R}$ that brings $\vec{\ell}$ *horizontal*, use
$$\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{-\ell_y}{\ell_x}\right) \tag{2a}\label{G2b}$$
or whenever $u_x$ is negative, negate both $u_x$ and $u_y$, i.e.
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} u_x \\ u_y \end{matrix} \right] = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{\ell_x^2 + \ell_y^2}}\left[ \begin{matrix} \ell_x \\ \ell_y \end{matrix} \right] , & \ell_x \ge 0 \\
\displaystyle \frac{-1}{\sqrt{\ell_x^2 + \ell_y^2}}\left[ \begin{matrix} \ell_x \\ \ell_y \end{matrix} \right] , & \ell_x \lt 0 \\
\end{cases} \tag{2a}\label{G2a}$$
(Apologies for the edits; had to iterate a couple of times to get the expressions right.)